# Am I forced to use SSH to connect to MySQL server with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a series of PHP scripts that make use of the **mysql_connect** function to connect to my database, like so:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
$myQuery = mysql_query('select * from myTable');
```

Which works on a local server but can't connect when it's on my actual website. I found this from my host, Namecheap:

> Remote MySQL connection is disabled on our shared servers due to security reasons, but you can easily set up an SSH tunnel between your computer and our server using an SSH client with the MySQL port 3306 forwarding.
>   https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1249/89/how-to-remotely-connect-to-mysql-database-located-on-our-shared-server

Which sounds to me like I can't connect to my own database without using SSH. So my questions are:

1. Do I have to use SSH to connect to my database in PHP?
2. Is there an easy of doing this in PHP, or should I buy a different type of hosting that doesn't have this restriction?

Note: I'm not asking how to connect with SSH, I'm just asking what my best option is going forward.

Comment: This restriction is only for when you want to connect to the database from the outside. When your code is on their servers you can just connect as usual.

Comment: You can connect directly from the PHP code on your server, but not from your development machine. In any case, please consider migrating from the `mysql_` functions (they were deprecated in PHP 5.5, which is so old that it no longer receives security updates, and completely removed in PHP 7). Instead, use `mysqli_` functions or PDO.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.